# How get emoji character from json_decode and store theme in mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, json, emoji, utf8mb4

I get data from file_get_contents method and convert this data to JSON
but when data contain an emoji character, I cannot give this field in JSON file and store it in database.
I changed table collation to utf8mb4_general_ci but do not work my code

```
$update = file_get_contents("php://input");
$update = json_decode($update, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

I tried to get JSON in $update and I also tried method below:

```
$firstname =isset($update["message"]["from"]["first_name"]) ? $update["message"]["from"]["first_name"] : "";
$lastname = isset($update["message"]["from"]["last_name"]) ? $update["message"]["from"]["last_name"] : "";
```

Comment: The emoji is inside the name? o_O

Comment: Can you share the JSON with us?

Comment: I read data in telegram API and some users set emoji in firstname field

Comment: when json contain emoji do not inssert to database but in this question save string with ??? character

Comment: Please provide the JSON string, too.  See "question mark" in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored